# Connecting Split Power planes for mixed signal PCB

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-layers, ferrite-bead, mixed-signal

I'm working on a mixed signal board, and I currently have 3 power planes, 12V, 3.3V analog, and 3.3V digital. I have a single GND plane with good separation between the analog and digital components. I don't have any traces crossing the power planes. My question is, should I connect the digital and analog power planes at a single point, I have seen people use ferrite bead, or should I just leave it split as it is?

Comment: Are they generated by different supplies/regulators?

Comment: If they should be supplied from a single regulator, then yes, some manner of filtering can be desirable.

Comment: They are generated by separate regulators.